# I can't pass value to a function

Tags: javascript, function

I am working with ESRI APIs and request JSON data from a server and I want to make a chart with this data so I request the data like that

```
Request(reqUrl, reqOptions).then(function (response) {
   *i do some stuff here with data which is going great *
    needsForAdmins(response.data)
  })

function needsForAdmins(response) {
    let librariesNeed = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < response.features.length; i++) {
        librariesNeed += response.features[i].attributes.library
    }


    let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['section', 'number', { role: 'style' }],
        ['library', librariesNeed , '#b7d1eb'],
    ]);

    let options = {
        bar: {
            groupWidth: "80%"
        },
        animation: {
            startup: true,
            duration: 1500,
            easing: "inAndOut"
        },
         legend: {
            position: 'none'
        }
    };

    let chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('needsForAdmins'));

    chartdraw(data2, options);
}
```

so every time I get the data from the server and make the function it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of undefined.

How can I pass the response to the function?

Comment: try `response.data.features`. Also console log `response` first to see what is its data type and what it contains

Comment: use `console.log(response)` to see the response structure

Comment: Check these docs out I don't think you using Request right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request

Comment: `console.log(response.data)` before calling `needsForAdmins(response)`

Comment: the response itself is undefined I don't know why because it is defined in the request body but when I pass it to the function it becomes undefined.

Comment: it doesn't become undefined because you call a function, clearly your `i do some stuff here` is overwriting `response.data`

Comment: @NoelKriegler - since `i do some stuff here with data which is going great` OP is probably not using *that* Request object (which is part of fetch API) :p

Comment: no, I used the response.data to pop up a drop-down list with the data

Comment: ok, so if you `console.log(response.data)` just before you `needsForAdmins(response.data)` - what do you see in your console output

Comment: Also ... what is `Request`?

Comment: @BravoI see the object structure.

Comment: @Bravo Request is a method in ESRI APIs like ajax call. it gets the data from ESRI server.

Comment: so, `console.log(response.data)` *just before calling* `needsForAdmins(response.data)` shows an object ... but `console.log(response);` as the first line in `needsForAdmins` function, shows `undefined`?

Comment: @bravo Exactly :D and i am going crazy cuz of that

Comment: indeed, that is not only odd, it's completely impossible - there must be something you're not showing, something important - are you sure the error is thrown at `for (let i = 0; i < response.features.length; i++) {`

Comment: @Bravo yes i am sure, maybe it is a bug in the request method, i will search fo it, thank you